# Unable to consume from Kafka topic using Karaf 4.3.1 with Camel 3.7.4

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-camel, apache-karaf

Hello i have a very simple camel route (trying to consume and log Kafka topic message):

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    super.configure();

    from(kafka())
            .routeId(INPUT_BROKER_ROUTE_ID)

            .log("KAFKA BODY ::: ${body}");
}

private static String kafka() {
    return new StringBuilder("kafka:")
            .append("{{kafka.topic}}")
            .append("?brokers=")
            .append("{{kafka.brokers}}")
            .append("&groupId=")
            .append("{{kafka.group.id}}")
            .append("&clientId=")
            .append("myClientId")
            .append("&autoOffsetReset=")
            .append("earliest")
            .append("&saslMechanism=")
            .append("PLAIN")
            .append("&securityProtocol=")
            .append(SASL_PLAINTEXT)
            .append("&saslJaasConfig=")
            .append(saslJaasConfig())
            .toString();
}

private static String saslJaasConfig() {
    return new StringBuilder(format("%s", PlainLoginModule.class.getCanonicalName()))
            .append(' ').append("required").append(' ')
            .append("username=")
            .append('"').append("{{kafka.username}}").append('"')
            .append(' ')
            .append("password=")
            .append('"').append("{{kafka.password}}").append('"')
            .append(';')
            .toString();
}
```

If i run unit test on this route i see topics message, but when i deploy this bundle i don't get any message from my topic and there is no error Karaf just show me this logs:

```
11:37:27.064 INFO [Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1] Successfully logged in.
11:37:27.067 WARN [Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1] The configuration 'specific.avro.reader' was supplied but isn't a known config.
11:37:27.068 INFO [Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1] Kafka version: 2.6.0
11:37:27.069 INFO [Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1] Kafka commitId: 62abe01bee039651
11:37:27.069 INFO [Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1] Kafka startTimeMs: 1624354647068
11:37:27.070 INFO [Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1] Route: input-broker-route started and consuming from: kafka://test
11:37:27.070 INFO [Camel (integ-norauto-v1-input) thread #75 - KafkaConsumer[test]] Subscribing test-Thread 0 to topic test
11:37:27.071 INFO [Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1] Total 1 routes, of which 1 are started
11:37:27.073 INFO [Camel (integ-norauto-v1-input) thread #75 - KafkaConsumer[test]] [Consumer clientId=myClientId, groupId=myGroupId] Subscribed to topic(s): test
11:37:27.073 INFO [Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1] Apache Camel 3.7.4 (integ-norauto-v1-input) started in 38ms
```

I do some tests and i see that even if i provide wrong username or password nothing happen (only when running on Karaf) it's look like it's not connected

Answer (score 1):

I finally found that is camel bug on LTS version 3.7.4 is resolved by using the latest camel version (3.10.0)...